# Using SAGA reclassification with tabled categories in QGIS script

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, saga

I am using QGIS, and I would like to write a script to help processing the data.

To do so, I have to reclassify heights values from a raster. I have written the following code, where `retab` is the path to the file containing the reclassification rules (see later) :

```
##Layer1=raster


from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import iface
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import os
import processing

retab = "E:\\Divers\\Qgis\\Scripts\\tab_reclass.txt"
#processing.runalg('saga:reclassifygridvalues', input, method, old, new, soperator, min, max, rnew, roperator, retab, toperator, nodataopt, nodata, otheropt, others, result)

Layerout=processing.runalg('saga:reclassifygridvalues', Layer1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, retab, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

The code gives the following error :

> Error: Wrong parameter value: E:\Divers\Qgis\Scripts\tab_reclass.txt

My rules are the following :

```
minimum maximum new
0   0.5 1
0.5 2   2
2   1000    3
```

I could not find a clear example on how to use the table rules, so I guess that it is where the error comes from.

If possible, I would prefer using the rules from the script rather than from the external file.

Comment: Is your rules file tab-delimited?

Comment: @Kazuhito yes it is

Comment: Mmm, then it should work. Could be an overkill, but how about preparing .mtab file? It is an associated file created by SAGA GUI  `Lookup Table | Save`. Not sure if it helps, though.

Comment: I don't get it, what's the use of that file? how would you use that in a Qgis environment?

Comment: I understand your suspicion. It is a definition (xml) file SAGA uses to read table, but I cannot say it works for your case.

Comment: @Kantan - Seems like you missed an additional parameter before `retab`. Try `Layerout=processing.runalg('saga:reclassifygridvalues', Layer1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, retab, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, None)` and see if it runs :)

Comment: @Joseph it looks like you were right, but there is still an error : IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should hopefully work:

```
##Layer1=raster

Layerout=processing.runalg('saga:reclassifygridvalues', Layer1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '0,0.5,1,0.5,2,2,2,1000,3', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, None)
```

---

*Notes:*

- No output is produced as I'm assuming you're going to process it further (but you can replace `runalg` with `runandload` to see what the output looks like.
- You can avoid using a lookup table by typing the `'minimum,maximum,new'` values in a string. So if you have 3 rows, you would type it continuously (e.g. `'minimum,maximum,new,minimum,maximum,new,minimum,maximum,new'`.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but good news, it works! Thanks for the notes too! For my application, I needed to get rid of the other values too, so here is my final command :

 `Layerout=processing.runandload('saga:reclassifygridvalues', Layer1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '0,0.5,1,0.5,2,2,2,1000,3', 0, 1, -99999, 1, -99999, none)`

Comment: @Kantan - Most welcome and nice one! Glad you got it to work :)